# A map of int and a set of pairs

Tags: c++, stl

Can I declare a map like this:

```
map<int,set<pair<int,int>>>
```

And if I can I want to do the following:

1. insert a pair in the set of map[i]
2. delete the first pair in the set of map[j]
3. traverse the map

Also please make use of auto keyword.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. Feel free to do the things you wish to do with this map.

Comment: Yes you can do all those things.  Have you tried to write any code? [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) is a very helpful site that shows you all about the standard library.

Comment: Yeah but I am getting confused with the usage of auto and pointer concept

Comment: _"Also please make use of auto keyword."_ Try to write the code without auto first and then look into what types you can replace with it. _"pointer concept"_ You do not need any pointers in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do all of the things that you have mentioned.

Declaration:

```
map<int,set<pair<int,int>>> m;
```

Insert a pair in the set of map[i]:

```
m[i].insert(make_pair(37,73));
```

Delete the first pair in the set of map[j]:

```
m[j].erase(m[j].begin());
```

Traverse the map:

```
for(auto x:m){
    cout<<"Key value: "<<x.first<<", Mapped Values: ";
    for(auto y:x.second){
        cout<<"("<<y.first<<", "<<y.second<<") ";
    }
cout<<endl;
}
```